# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /questions/new Couldn't find Language without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm building an app that has a language model, a question model, and an answer model.  I am new to programming and running into the following error when I try to click on a link to a "New Question" form from the questions index page:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /questions/new
Couldn't find Language without an ID
/controllers/questions_controller.rb line 81 at @language = Language.find(params[:language_id])
Request parameters  
{"action"=>"new", "controller"=>"questions"}
routes nil
```

Here are my routes:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :users

  resources :languages do
    resources :questions, except: [:index] do 
      resources :answers
    end
   end

  resources :questions, only: [:index, :new]

  get 'about' => 'welcome#about'
  root to: 'welcome#index' 
  end
```

Here is my questions_controller.rb:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_language, except: [:index]
  before_action :set_question, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @questions = current_user.questions
  end

  def show
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    @answer = Answer.new
  end

  def new
    @question = Question.new
    authorize @question
  end

  def edit
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    authorize @question
  end

  def update
     @question = Question.find(params[:id])
     authorize @question

     if @question.update_attributes(question_params)
       flash[:notice] = "Question was updated."
       redirect_to [@language, @question]
     else
       flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the question. Please try again."
       render :edit
     end
   end

  def create
     @question = Question.new(question_params)
     @question.language = @language
     @question.user = current_user
     authorize @question

     if @question.save
       flash[:notice] = "Question was saved."
       redirect_to [@language, @question]
     else
       flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the question. Please try again."
       render :new
     end
   end
  def destroy
    @question.destroy.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to questions_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_question
      @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    end

    def question_params
      params.require(:question).permit(:id, :body)

    end

    def set_language
      @language = Language.find(params[:language_id])
    end

end
```

Here is my question model:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
      require 'obscenity/active_model'
      has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy=>true
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :language

      default_scope { order('created_at DESC') }


      validates :body, obscenity: true
      validates :body, length: { minimum: 10, maximum: 160 }, presence: true
      validates :user, presence: true

    end
```

Here is my questions index view:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
      <h3>My Questions</h3>
      <% @questions.each do |question| %>
         <div class="media">
           <div class="media-body">
             <h4 class="media-heading">
      <p><%= question.language ? link_to(question.body, [question.language, question]) : question.body %></p>
            </h4>
            <small>
               submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(question.created_at) %> ago by <%= question.user.name %> <br/>
               <%= question.answers.count %> Answers
             </small>
           </div>
         </div>
      <% end %>
       </div>
       <br/>
       <br/>
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= link_to "Ask a New Question", new_question_path, class: 'btn btn-success' %>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I've spent a considerable amount of time trying to fix the error through research and trial and error, but I'm at a loss.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Let me know if you need to see any other files.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `set_language` method of QuestionsController.

`Language.find(params[:language_id])` is raising an error because you're visiting the url `/questions/new`, which doesn't contain any information about a language, so `params[:language_id]` equals `nil`. So your code is attempting to find a Language whose ID is nil, which doesn't exist - so it raises an error.

If you run the task `rake routes` (or visit `localhost:3000/rails/info/routes` in newer versions of Rails) you can see detailed information about the routes generated by `config/routes.rb` - In your case you've actually got TWO routes to create a new question:

`/languages/:language_id/questions/new      new_language_question_path`
`/questions/new                             new_question_path`

What this means is, if you visit `questions/new` then `params[:language_id]` will equal `nil`, which is what's causing your error (because you're trying to find a language with ID nil, which doesn't exist.) If you visit `/languages/1/questions/new`, then `params[:language_id]` will equal 1, which should be fine assuming that a Language with ID `1` actually exists.

It depends on the specifics of your app (should the "Add a new question' link take the user to create a new question *for a specific language*? Or should it be a general page for creating a new question which may or may not have a language?), but two solutions to your error could be:

1. Change `link_to ..., new_question_path` to `link_to ..., new_language_question_path(language)`, where `language` is whatever language you want the link to create a new question for.
2. Change  `before_action :set_language, except: [:index]` to `before_action :set_language, except: [:index, :new]` in `QuestionsController`... so you don't try and call `Language.find` with no ID. (You'll then need to make sure that there are no references to `@language` in  `/app/views/questions/new.html.erb`, because that variable won't be set.)

I hope this is clear! Tell me if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeMillo!  I went with option number 2 and it worked like a charm!  I really appreciate all of your help!